# Finite models for Systems of Incidence and Parallelism Axioms?

Tags: abstract-algebra, geometry

I'm reading Shafarevich's *Basic Notions of Algebras*, my question is at the end of these prints.

> [image]
>   [image]
>   [image]
>   [image]

---

I don't understand what's the connection of that linear equations (in the end of the quoted text) with the lines in $Fig.1$, could you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For line $AB$ we have to find its equation; the general equation of a line in coordinate geometry is:

> $ax + by + c = 0$.

We want that point $A, B$ satisfy it (we want that it contains them); thus we sustitute in turn the coordinates of $A,B$ into the equation to get :

> for $A(0,0)$ : $a \times 0 + b \times 0 + c = 0$, i.e. $c=0$
>
> for $B(0,1)$ : $a \times 0 + b \times 1 = 0$, (we have already calculated : $c=0$) i.e. $b \times 1 = 0$, from which : $b=0$.

Thus the equation of $AB$ must be :

> > $ax = 0$.

We divide both side by $a$ getting :

> $x = 0$.

For $AD$, the line through $A(0,0)$ and $D(1,1)$, it is easily verified that the two points satisfy the equation : $1 \times x + 1 \times y = 0$ :

> for $A(0,0)$ : $1 \times 0 + 1 \times 0 = 0$
>
> for $D(1,1)$ : $1 \times 1 + 1 \times 1 = 1 + 1 = 0$, from table for $+$.

The same for $BC$ : $1 \times x + 1 \times y = 1$ :

> for $B(0,1)$ : $1 \times 0 + 1 \times 1 = 1$
>
> for $C(1,0)$ : $1 \times 1 + 1 \times 0 = 1$.

Comment: I don't understand one thing: Why does he says that the equation for $AB:1X=0$, you're saying that the equation is $ax=0$. Is $a=1$?

Comment: @Vÿska - because the two equations define the same line; it is the line of point $P(0,n)$ for $n$ whatever. If we substitute the coordinate of $P$ (we really need only the x-coord) in equation $x=0$ or $ax=0$, we get the same result : $0=0$, i.e. the two equations are satisfied by the same set of point; i.e. they coincide.

Comment: @Vÿska - the above consideration holds in general; for the specific "model", you have to consider that in it we have only two numbers : $0$ and $1$. Thus, if $a \ne 0$, then it must be $a = 1$.